# how to get percentage appeared as a string right next to a number in each cell in data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have a data frame as:

```
           Love   Hate Total
Yes          39     42    81
No            0      0     0
Missing       3      0     3
```

How to I have a result as:

```
                    Love         Hate         Total
Yes           39 (48.2%)   42 (51.9%)   81 (100.0%)
No             0 (00.0%)    0 (00.0%)    0 (100.0%)
Missing       3 (100.0%)    0 (00.0%)    3 (100.0%)
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: have a look at the prop.table function but first of all show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried percent <- round(mydata * 100/length(mydata), digits = 1)
result <- paste(percent, "%", sep = "")
result

Comment: it came out absolutely way far from what i expected it to be :(

Comment: Is it just for printing purposes ?

Comment: @Tensibai: yes it just for printing purpose

Comment: I assume Ananda answer cover it all anyway.

Comment: **Edit** your question to include the output you get when you run `dput(data)`.

Comment: Ah I got it. Yes Ananda's solution has solved my problem. Many thanks to all for taking your time on my question. I really appreciate it. Have a nice day everyone!

Comment: No problem. In the future, please share your data in a reproducible format (as was done in all of the answers provided at this question). It makes it easier for others to identify where the trouble might lie.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, `prop.table` will be part of the answer here. Note that we will have `addmargins` create the "Total" column for us when using `prop.table`.

Here's a possible approach:

```
## Use prop.table and addmargins to get the raw data
x <- addmargins(prop.table(as.matrix(mydf[, -3]), margin = 1) * 100, 2)
## use sprintf to format the percentage
x <- data.frame(`dim<-`(sprintf("(%2.1f%%)", replace(x, is.nan(x), 0)), dim(x)))

## Use Map to paste together the values from your original data frame and x
mydf[] <- Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y), mydf, x)
```

Or just, as pointed out by @Pierre.

```
mydf[] <- Map(paste, mydf, x)
```

The result:

```
mydf
##               Love       Hate       Total
## Yes     39 (48.1%) 42 (51.9%) 81 (100.0%)
## No        0 (0.0%)   0 (0.0%)    0 (0.0%)
## Missing 3 (100.0%)   0 (0.0%)  3 (100.0%)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) {
  sprintf("%d (%2.1f%%)", x, ifelse(x == 0, 0, x/mydf[["Total"]]*100))
})
```

---

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Love = c(39L, 0L, 3L), Hate = c(42L, 0L, 0L), 
        Total = c(81L, 0L, 3L)), .Names = c("Love", "Hate", "Total"),
        row.names = c("Yes", "No", "Missing"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

***Update for a `matrix` as input***

If you have a `matrix` as the input, the process would be mostly the same (actually, a little bit easier):

```
M <- as.matrix(mydf)

x <- addmargins(prop.table(M[, -3], margin = 1) * 100, 2)
x <- `dim<-`(sprintf("(%2.1f%%)", replace(x, is.nan(x), 0)), dim(x))

M[] <- paste(M, x)
M
#         Love         Hate         Total        
# Yes     "39 (48.1%)" "42 (51.9%)" "81 (100.0%)"
# No      "0 (0.0%)"   "0 (0.0%)"   "0 (0.0%)"   
# Missing "3 (100.0%)" "0 (0.0%)"   "3 (100.0%)"
```

You get nicer looking output in this case as a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(M)
#               Love       Hate       Total
# Yes     39 (48.1%) 42 (51.9%) 81 (100.0%)
# No        0 (0.0%)   0 (0.0%)    0 (0.0%)
# Missing 3 (100.0%)   0 (0.0%)  3 (100.0%)
```

Comment: Or shorten the first with `Map(paste, mydf, x)`

Comment: @PNY, do you have a `data.frame` or a `matrix` as your input? Please share the `dput` of your data, and as Pierre Lafortune suggests, also let us know what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Provided : 
Love <- table(l$status)
Hate <- table(h$status)
x <- cbind(Love, Hate)
y <- cbind(sum((l$status)=="n"), sum((h$status=="n")))
mydf <- rbind(x, y)
data<- mydf[c(2, 3, 1), ]
rownames(data) <- list("Yes", "No", "Missing")
data

Comment: @PNY, that doesn't look like the output of `dput(data)` (which should be part of your question, by the way). It also doesn't look like a `data.frame`.

Comment: I tried to modified a bit to match my case following Pierre suggested but i still didnt come out

Comment: [[1]]
[1] "39 (48.1%)"  "39 (0.0%)"   "39 (100.0%)"

[[2]]
[1] "0 (51.9%)" "0 (0.0%)"  "0 (0.0%)" 

[[3]]
[1] "3 (100.0%)" "3 (0.0%)"   "3 (100.0%)"

[[4]]
[1] "42 (48.1%)"  "42 (0.0%)"   "42 (100.0%)"

[[5]]
[1] "0 (51.9%)" "0 (0.0%)"  "0 (0.0%)" 

[[6]]
[1] "0 (100.0%)" "0 (0.0%)"   "0 (100.0%)"

Comment: that's how it came out :(

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that produces the desired print out

```
df<- matrix(sample(1:100,size = 3*2,replace = T),nrow = 3) # A sample matrix
df<- cbind(df, rowSums(df))

t(apply( df,1, function(x) paste0(x, " (", round(100*x/tail(x,1),2), "%)" )))
```

Comment: Firstly Thanks a mil 
And this is how it came out
        [,1]          [,2]          [,3]       
Yes     "39 (48.15%)" "42 (51.85%)" "81 (100%)"
No      "0 (NaN%)"    "0 (NaN%)"    "0 (NaN%)" 
Missing "3 (100%)"    "0 (0%)"      "3 (100%)"

Comment: In deed, `0 / 0` is indeterminate and it is natural to assign `NA` to that expression. If you do not find `NA`s legible you can surpress it any time by `print(foo, na="-")`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a way it might work:

```
df = data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(3,4,5,6,7,8))
names(df) = c('v1', 'v2')
df$p1 = format(df$v1/df$v2, digits = 2)
df$v1_p1 = paste0(df$v1, "(", df$p1, "%)")
df
```